# jQuery split/chunk selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a list of

```
<ul>
   <li>blabla</li> <!-- About 800 or more in some occasions -->
</ul>
```

is there away to select in chunks so this does not make the page unresponsive?

because selecting all at once causes the browser to crash and be unresponsive,
so I could make it select lets say first hundred then second hundred and so on.

Comment: Did you looked at my edited answer?

Comment: usualy selecting dom elements does not take a lot of time, even if you get 8000 of them. What thales time is to bind some event on every one of them, thats why you should consider Seths answer. Some experiment with 2000 divs: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ZL8/1/

Comment: I was moving them all at once, which caused the problem using the answer below splice, i managed to shift 100 list at once, and let the user wait for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy! jquery `:lt()` and jquery `.slice()`

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
    $('li:lt(100)') 
$('li').slice(100)
```

Comment: Edited again... Hope you like it

Comment: yep slice is like the one :) i'll give this a go :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean when you say "select" you could use the `.delegate()` method.

```
$('ul').delegate('li', 'click', function(){

    // Your Code

});
```

I would also recommend using an ID rather than just `$('ul')`

Comment: I have `var all = $('#ul_id li');` and some other stuff to do with it later... If i have lets say 100, 200 its ok it works find but more than that it chocks the page memory.

Comment: Delegate works really well because it says "You have an UI that you've just attached an event to! O hey, you just clicked this UL, let me check to see if this any LI's, it does! Now let me run this function on this one LI!!!" It basically doesn't attach an event to every LI, just the UL and then it targets the specific element after it's been clicked.

Comment: @val its the stuff later that makes it slow, not the selection. Take a look at the comment i left on your question.